# How to update user roles to Spring Security with Spring Boot in a REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I´m facing a problem, I have an Rest Application with Spring Boot and secure access of URLs by Spring security.

This configuration is

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        montarPermissoesByUsuario(auth);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void montarPermissoesByUsuario(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    Set<CsUsuario> usuarios = serviceUsuario.findUsuariosApp();

    for (CsUsuario csUsuario : usuarios) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(csUsuario.getUsername()).password(csUsuario.getPassword())
                .roles(this.montarRoles(csUsuario));
    }
}

public String[] montarRoles(CsUsuario usuario) {
    String[] roles = null;

    for (CsGrupo grupo : usuario.getGrupos()) {
        roles = grupo.getServicosApp().stream().map(CsServicoApp::getRegra).toArray(String[]::new);
    }
    return roles;
}
```

And the access of Data Base from Spring Data JPA

```
public interface CsUsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<CsUsuario, String>{

public CsUsuario findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

@Query(value = CsUsuarioQuery.USUARIO_APP, nativeQuery = true)
public Set<CsUsuario> findUsuariosApp();
```

}

In a class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

But, instead of including users and roles in this code, I get from base data, because I'm working with a unique data base of users for some systems.

My problem is, the configure works only when I start my application on Spring Boot, if the user has any update of roles even the configuration is established from database, Spring Boot doesnt update after started.

I would know if someone already uses Spring Boot with this scenario, and if this is possible.

In research I found some implementations to update bean InMemoryUserDetailsManager by Rest Controller, in this case I´ll need implement a PUT to Rest Controller of InMemoryUserDetailsManager to update roles?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you consider to use a database instead of in memory users data? If you'll use a database to store your users and roles, it would be easier to update and save new roles for existing users

Comment: Hi, thank you for a reply, So, I already using database to store my users and their roles and this is the problem. Spring Boot doesnt update my roles once I has some change in my database.

Comment: Can you share the code of how you are accessing data from database and are you using any chaching technology?

Comment: Your roles are updating in DB but not in the browser?

Comment: Yes, my roles updating in DB from another web application, but not update to Spring security application.

Comment: what do you mean by "security application"?

Comment: I have 2 applications that use the same data base, the application REST doesnt update de roles after start by spring boot. This roles are update by another application, I mean, after start my spring boot app, I need update roles or include new users to access the system without restart spring boot app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First implementation was correct, I was testing on a browser and always insert user and password in a session, My mistake, sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring boot and your browser doesn't update your views, you need to add these two lines to your application.properties configuration file:

```
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
```

you can take further reading here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content

Comment: Thank you for a reply, but this doesnt work for me. My spring boot with REST keep with the same roles of start application and dont update if I change roles on data base.